# 2 where condition one SQL sentence

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch that SQL rows:

```
SELECT aa.*
FROM Answers AS aa
WHERE event_id = 1 AND
      ( (aa.form_item_id = 1 AND form_item_reply = "John") AND
        (aa.form_item_id = 2 AND form_item_reply = "Doe")
      )
ORDER BY aa.id DESC
```

But it's given wrong result, I want to fetch that `(aa.form_item_id = 1 AND form_item_reply = "John")` and `(aa.form_item_id = 2 AND form_item_reply = "Doe")`.

It have to give me above 2 condition result.

Comment: Your condition cannot be valid on a single row.  Hence, I don't understand the question.

Comment: The WHERE cause looks at one `answers`row in the table at a time. This row's `form_item_id` cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time. Are you maybe looking for all event IDs for which both answers 1/John, 2/Doe exist? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You don't need parenthesis nor alias here unless you plan to use OR too perhaps ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR

```
SELECT aa.* FROM Answers AS aa WHERE event_id = 1 AND 
( 
(aa.form_item_id = 1 AND form_item_reply = "John") 
OR (aa.form_item_id = 2 AND form_item_reply = "Doe") 
) ORDER BY aa.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want `OR`:

```
SELECT aa.*
FROM Answers AS aa
WHERE event_id = 1 AND
      ( (aa.form_item_id = 1 AND form_item_reply = 'John') OR
        (aa.form_item_id = 2 AND form_item_reply = 'Doe')
      )
ORDER BY aa.id DESC
```

Comment: It is not I want to, It has to ensure the two of them